# Timestamp index for pandas dataframe from read_json()

Tags: python, json, pandas, timestamp

I'm reading a single JSON line from file data.json with this content:

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": 1436266865,
    "rates": {
      "EUR": 0.911228,
      "JPY": 122.5463,
      "AUD": 1.346118
    }
  },
  {
    "timestamp": 1436277661,
    "rates": {
      "JPY": 122.4789,
      "AUD": 1.348871,
      "EUR": 0.91433
    }
  }
]
```

into a pandas DataFrame.  I want to use the "timestamp" as the DataFrame's index.  I achieve this by:

```
df = pandas.read_json('data.json')
df.index = df['timestamp']
df.drop('timestamp', axis=1, inplace=1)
```

Is it possible to do it in just one line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('data.json')
df.set_index('timestamp',inplace=True)
print(df)
```

What this will do is set `timestamp` to your index. `inplace=True` will prevent you having to do `df=df.set_index('timestamp')` and by default it'll drop the column.

```
                                                        rates
timestamp                                                    
1436266865  {'EUR': 0.9112279999999999, 'JPY': 122.5463, '...
1436277661  {'JPY': 122.4789, 'AUD': 1.348871, 'EUR': 0.91...
```

Comment: What one-line are you referring to?

Comment: Why this one-liner wouldn't work?      `df = pd.read_json('data.json').set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)`

Comment: Because the `dataframe` has not been set yet, so you can't call `.set_index` on it unless it has been executed in memory. The code is being done from left to right after it's been read from right to left. So calling on `.set_index` for an undefined DF will result in `None`. Does that clarify things?